# How to format string in python

Tags: python

I just cannot to format of a string:

```
id = "3123123"
a = '{"classes": [], "field": {}}'.format(id)
print(a)
```

[image]

All suggestions will be nice !

Comment: `a = '{{"classes": [], "field": {}}}'.format(id)`

Comment: Put a 0 in between the curly braces to signal, that the first parameter in format() corresponds to the first index (0) in your string. If you want to use more than one variable you can increment this number like: a = 'Some{0} is {1}'.format('thing', 'weird')
Edit: To escape curly braces in a format string, use double braces like @Shijith did

Comment: Or: `a = f'{{"classes": [], "field": {id}}}'`

Comment: Thanks a lot , all stuff was very useful !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formatting string clashes with the [formatting placeholder specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

You'll need to escape the `{` with `{{`

```
a = '{{"classes": [], "field": {{}}}}'.format(id)
```

And a make sure there is a placeholder for `id` in the formatting string with `{}`

Comment: thanks a lot ! This was useful